Deforming a mesh onto one or more others
I am trying to simulate the process of gluing thick but flexible (think thick rubber bands) parts on top of one another. That is: not modeling the end result but actually achieving it via simulation or deformation or similar.
What I am looking for (I did model this one) is to be able to go from here:

to here:

by way of a set of modifiers or geometry nodes.
Basic requirements:

the part that is "glued" will have some thickness to it
there is no guarantee that the target parts (the one being glued onto) will be a single one (see pictures)
there is no guarantee per se that the part is being glued in the same direction of gravity

I was trying something similar to this but it doesn't work if the target surfaces belong to many meshes.
Any ideas?
I've tried

joining the target surfaces into one mesh
using lattice and deforming
and then the smooth modifier

but I get all the jagged edges as here:

Using python and programming is ok.

You can get pretty decent results with a node tree like this. Basically setting up a shrinkwrap modifier but with the multiple objects you want to shrinkwrap to in a collection. After some experimentation I decided on voxel-remeshing the collection because it smoothed the target geo out and prevented weird clipping issues. You can omit that part if you want, just go straight from Realize Instances into the Raycast node.

The rest of the full modifier stack, you can add another SubSurf mod after this to smooth things out if need be:

Result:

